# pointer disappears in gimp/krita with graphic tablet (wayland)

Tags: gimp, wayland, krita

i have a xp-pen g430 graphic tablet, the vendor drivers never worked for me but recently discovered that in ubuntu 18.04 wayland the tablet was somehow recognized and, finally, usable with the digimend driver (https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/releases/tag/v9).
The problem is that in krita or gimp, the pointer becomes independent to the mouse, and disappears when outside the canvas, which makes it hard to select another tool, etc. The mouse can be used for this, but is somehow overrided by the stylus, so nothing can be selected with the mouse until you touch something outside the program window...

in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-digimend.conf i have:

```
#
# InputClass sections for some tablets supported by the DIGImend kernel
# drivers. Organized into separate InputClass sections based on (one of) the
# advertised brands. Mostly because the MatchUSBID options would become too
# long otherwise.
#
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Huion tablets with Wacom driver"
    MatchUSBID "5543:006e|256c:006e"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Ugee/XP-Pen tablets with Wacom driver"
    MatchUSBID "28bd:007[145]|28bd:0094|28bd:0042|5543:004[57]|5543:0081|5543:0004|5543:3031"
    # Exclude the original WP5540U which PID is reused by Ugee M540
    NoMatchProduct "MousePen"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Ugtizer tablets with Wacom driver"
    MatchUSBID "2179:0053"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Yiynova tablets with Wacom driver"
    MatchUSBID "5543:004d"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

(my tablet is in 28bd:007, but `xsetwacom --list devices` ouputs nothing)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue, however in my case there's two independent cursors (mouse and graphic table) and the graphic table simply disappears (but somehow moving back and forth different windows it comes back)

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754806

According to this issue, Magnification could cause the cursor to be missing. Do you happen to have it enabled?

Comment: hey thanks. I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (X11) and started working out of the box. Thankfuly